# Sequenced column not incrementing (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: jpa, sql-server-2012, entity, sequence, alter-table

I'm trying to add an id column to an existing table, since it is needed to work around a problem with Hibernate. So, I would like to add an id column to that table, which would be the primary key for the table and each row would get a value starting from 1 and incrementing until the last row in the table. However, the column only gets value as zero (0) for every row at the moment. How can I get it to increment correctly? Thank you.

I have the following SQL-query:

```
ALTER TABLE service_history
ADD id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('service_history_seq')
GO
PRIMARY KEY (id)
CREATE SEQUENCE service_history_seq AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
```

And in the ServiceHistory entity I have the following code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "serviceHistorySeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "serviceHistorySeq", sequenceName = "service_history_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you maybe confusing MYSQL or Oracle with Microsoft SQL.  You want an Identity column which is coded like this

```
ALTER TABLE service_history ADD id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Here is a [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)